# define a precision accuracy QGIS project

Tags: qgis, accuracy, precision

How to define a precision accuracy of decimal places in  QGIS project or where I use digitizing to add new features ?

for example I have a point or polygon and true coordinates of vertex have to many precision like this `14521.124545421` , `454411.4545441414` I want only precision 3 of digits.I say the true coordinates to take some point where I add in QGIS I don't mean in attribute table using X or Y there I can easy to define precision.
first I think to change precision is `project - project properties - general - precision` but that is only for display....that is easy work in `ARCGIS` and I want to QGIS.

Comment: If I set the precision through project properties then the number of decimal places I set is reflected in both the coordinate display in the bottom bar, which you can use to show where you're digitising and in the Identify Results point X and Y.  It won't transfer across the attribute table (If I used $X to write the x coordinate for example) but you can set the precision of this separately.  Where else are you interested in setting the precision?  Could you post a link to how it is done in Arc?

Comment: @Ed Rollason that set is only for display if you try to see real coordinate of points where you digitizing then you see different precision.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by real coordinate?  Where are you viewing it while you're digitising?  Can you add a screen shot to your original post.

Comment: I mean the true coordinate to keep QGIS for any point,for simple example if you have  precision 2 decimal on project properties and try to Identify point then you look other precision if create on attributes $X and $Y and define precision 4 decimal places then you look the diference the last decimal is not 0 .if use MySQL or postgis database then you look in database have many precision.